# Turning C output into C# input

Tags: c#, c, pipe

I am currently trying to develop a program which takes the output of an existing program (written in C) and uses it as input (in C#).  The problem I am having is that the existing program prints data in redundant format but it dynamically changes. An example could be a random name generator and I need to make a program that logs all of the random names as they appear.

Could I just pipe this and the output will be grabbed as it comes? The C program is run from a CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect the output streams from the Process object to get direct access to it. You make a call and it will invoke an event of your choice when output is received. One of my questions may provide some explanation on how to do this - [`C# Shell - IO redirection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060799/c-shell-io-redirection):

```
processObject.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processObject.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(processObject_OutputDataReceived);
/* ... */
processObject.Start();
processObject.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

And then later:

```
public void processObject_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    ProcessNewData(e.Data);
}
```

Note that this includes the trailing newline.

Or you can just pipe it and use `Console.ReadLine` to read it in. On the command line, you would execute:

```
cprogram | csharp_program
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this directly with the Process object - just use the method above. If you do choose to go this route, you can use:

```
string input = "";
int currentChar = 0;

while ( (currentChar = Console.Read()) > -1 ) {
    input += Convert.ToChar(currentChar);
}
```

Which will read from the input until EOF.

Comment: Hmm I may have been slightly misleading in my description.  The original program is written in C but is executed via CLI in Linux.  Some of the existing libraries only exist on the Linux side of this machine as well so I may be trying in vain to get this to work in C# (but C# is so nice for GUI's!)

Comment: Oh, CLI! I read it as CLR. Oops. :-)
You could get your program to work in Mono - most do without modification.

Comment: I was trying to find a version of Mono for RHELv5 but all I saw was "other lisnux" hahah guess its better than nothing.

Comment: Try the version for Fedora or standard Red Hat. These *might* be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If the C# program is also command-line based, running this command from the command-line will chain them together:

```
my_c_program.exe | my_csharp_program.exe
```

The C# program will receive the output of the C program, via its standard input stream (`Console.Read`, etc.)